# D Automatic Type Errors (64 bit issue?)

Tags: types, casting, d, type-inference

A little background: I am on Mac OSX Lion (64 bit, obviously) and I am a long time Java developer interested in learning D.

I picked up a copy of *The D Programming Language* and I am confused on a few things. First, if I try something like the following (straight from the book):

```
int[] months = new int[12];
foreach (i, ref month; months) {
    month = i + 1;
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (i + 1LU) of type ulong to int

This is fixed by changing `i` to `int i`.

I think this is because the automatic type for numbers on a 64 bit platform is `ulong` and so type inference doesn't really work out.

Now I have the following problem:

```
bool binarySearch(T)(T[] input, T value) {
    // ...
    int i = input.length / 2;
    // ...
}
```

That returns the following compile error:

> Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (input.length / 2LU) of type ulong to int

Casting fixes this, but I'd rather not. I also get other silly errors relating to getting `long` values from calculations and then not being able to use them for indexing into arrays. Is D's 64 bit support just not up to snuff yet? What can I do to avoid trouble in the future while learning D? Having to explicitly use casts and types everywhere seems to be the opposite of what attracted me to the language in the first place...

Comment: Note: This is only "silly" because you haven't used C, and in Java, architecture-independent code doesn't really exist. So you're either forced to use 32-bit integers or 64-bit integers in Java to index an array, whereas in C (and D), you should use `size_t` when indexing an array. This makes your code much more correct (and platform-independent), though of course, D handles this typing for you. (In both C and D, `size_t` is almost always automatically aliased to either an unsigned 32-bit integer or an unsigned 64-bit, which is why you're seeing one of those names instead of `size_t`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think this is because the automatic type for numbers on a 64 bit platform is ulong and so type inference doesn't really work out.

Correct. If this is an error in TDPL, you should probably submit errata. The index variable of `foreach` statements is usually always of type `size_t`.

> Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (input.length / 2LU) of type ulong to int

Change your code to:

```
size_t i = input.length / 2;
```

Or even better, so you don't have to think about this:

```
auto i = input.length / 2;
```

What you're seeing is, in fact, full-blown 64-bit arrays support. `size_t` resolves to the native integer type, and is what is used for array indexing and array lengths.

Answer (score 0):

on the future

to someone

```
int[] months = new int[12];
foreach (int i, ref month; months) {
    month = i + 1;
}
```